# Update fields in sync/update in real time

Tags: jira

I created a post function which will copy parents summary and description to custom fields called parent summary and parent description on a subtask. It happens whenever a new subtask is created under the parent.

Now I have an ask that whenever summary or description is updated, it should update in both places, if updated in the parent, then update should reflect in subtask and vice versa.

How can I achieve this? any thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Write a listener that responds to the 'issue updated' event.

More info about jira event listeners is available [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/listeners-938846909.html).

You didn't mention whether you're writing a custom add-on or a script for the [Script Runner add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.onresolve.jira.groovy.groovyrunner/server/overview), but here are links to more info for both options:

- [add-on tutorial about writing your own event listener](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/writing-jira-event-listeners-with-the-atlassian-event-library/)
- [how to write a listener script using the Script Runner add-on](https://scriptrunner.adaptavist.com/latest/jira/listeners.html#_custom_listeners)

Comment: I was trying to write a custom listener using script runner.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do update them with the use of event listener with the update event and getting the history of the fieldHistory() routine in SIL here is the documentation link: https://confluence.cprime.io/display/SIL/fieldHistory

after that you can know check if the values are changed the if changed you can update those  subtask details by getting the subtask of the parent issue using subtasks() routine in SIL. you can either use getIssueFields() routine for getting the field or you can just use the key then field to change their value check this link for more details about get the fields using the string key https://confluence.cprime.io/display/SIL/Variable+Resolution

then use lfSet() for changing the value of each fields.

here is the link of the documentation of SIL : https://confluence.cprime.io/display/SIL